# When creating new row in table on click it appears only momentarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to create an interactive table where a new row and three columns are created when one button (clockin) is clicked, filling in the first cell with the current time. When the second button is clicked (clockout) it fills in the second cell of the last row with the current time. The problem is that the newly added information doesn't stay on the page. Is there a slick way I can actively update the code every time the button is clicked?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 timebtns">
    <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="clockin" name="clockin" class="btn btn-success" value="Clock In" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="clockout" name="clockout" class="btn btn-danger" value="Clock Out" />
    </form>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td><h2>In</h2></td>
        <td><h2>Out</h2></td>
        <td><h2>Total</h2></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>InData</td>
        <td>OutData</td>
        <td>TotalData</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds(); //set variable to current time

$("#clockin").click(function(){
    $('table tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+time+'</td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
});

$("#clockout").click(function(){
        $('table tr:last td:nth-child(2)').append(time);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your clockout click function the line

```
$('table tr:last nth:child(2)').append(time);
```

is wrong. The correct format is:

```
$('table tr:last td:nth-child(2)').append(time);
```